# Getting sub folders by name with windows cmd

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

Within a batch-script, I would like to list all subfolders with a given name. I can do it in general but have problems, when there is subfolder direclty in the folder where I am searching. I am doing this on Windows 7 cmd.

Code I use to list all subfolders with name bin:

```
dir /s /q /b /A:D bin
```

If I have a folder structure like this: `".\a\bin .\b\bin .\c\bin"` it works fine.

if I have structure like this: `".\bin .\a\bin .\b\bin .\c\bin"` it only lists the content of `".\bin"`.

Does anybody know any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dir /s /b /A:D *|findstr /ri "[\\]bin$"
```